# Bitcoin Core RPC goes does down

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have issues running Bitcoin core.

Steps

1. Install brand new Windows Server 2012 machine.
2. I installed Bitcoin core.
3. It ran ok for 8 hours.
4. RPC server of bitcoin core goes down.
5. When I do CMD> netstat -an (to see the running ports.)

   - I cannot see port 8332 running ( also no response )
   - 8333 is running.

Please help,
Thank you

Comment: How did you configure your RPC server? What are the contents of your `bitcoin.conf` file? Did you run it through the Qt client or the command line interface?

Comment: In addition to what George has asked please provide a copy of debug.log found in %appdata%/bitcoin

Comment: Rpc server works for 4 hours than it goes down.

Comment: I suspect the wallet.dat is corrupt. After running the salvage it said there are corrupt parts in the db